# Why isn't Apache starting on xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Sorry, I searched a lot and i know that there are lots of posts reporting problems like this but none of them helped me.
I installed xampp on Windows 8 but when I click to start apache it doesn't work, it just displays "Attempting to start MySQL service..." without starting.

Comment: Any relevant logs will be handy.

Comment: We generally don't consider *AMP installations on client OS to be topical here.

Comment: I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794829/xampp-on-windows-apache-not-starting

now it works!